# cron/ fcron bootrun option: how to use?

Tags: cron, bootrun

I have a well working fcron on my WSL Ubuntu 18.04. however I could not get the `bootrun` option to take effect:

```
&bootrun 0 * * * * echo "make a log entry $(date)" >>  ~/myfiles/fcron/testlog.log
```

according to the [fcron documentation](http://fcron.free.fr/doc/en/fcrontab.5.html#FCRONTAB.5.BOOTRUN) the `bootrun` option tells fcron to execute jobs that have been missed due to the system being shut off. So when I turn on the computer, i should find those log entries for every hour during the previous night. However, this is not happening. There are only log entries from then my computer was running. how can i Fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me, fcron v. 3.3.1

```
&runatreboot,runonce 0 * * * * echo "make a log entry $(date)" >>  ~/myfiles/fcron/testlog.log
```